# How to Add Dimpled Holes to Textured Bar Tape w/ Screw Modifier?

Tags: texturing, uv, screw-modifier

Goal: Apply this textured bar tape around a pull up bar

So far I have been able to apply the bar tape thanks to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oxCU4m6dBY), however I want to add the dimple holes to the tape (See image) however I am at a loss as the screw modifier doesn't seem to like when the profile goes from 1-D to 2-D.

Any thoughts?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the material for the tape?  I suspect the answer lies in modifying the material and possibly doing some UV mapping.

Comment: Hi :). Do you want these dimples to be real geometry? Normal/Bump map should work well enough.

Answer (score 1):

- If you construct your handlebars, at least initially, from the native
  (round) 'Bevel' of a curve,set in its *Data* tab > *Geometry* panel,
  you can use the same curve to deform the spiral of tape.
- If you make the spiral by using a *Screw* modifier on a single line of geometry, offset from its object origin, then the 'Stretch U' and 'Stretch V' settings in the modifier  will give you texture coordinates to work with:

[image]

... as you can see, the positions of the vertices in the line are somewhat counter-intuitive. They have been adjusted to the scene, after the other modifiers are showing their effect. Kick off with a straight line, and tweak later.

The line is given:

1. The *Screw* modifier, to make the tape spiral
2. A *Curve* modifier, aimed at the handlebar-curve
3. A *Solidify* modifier, to give it a slight thickness
4. A *Bevel* modifier, limited by angle, to sharpen the rim generated by the *Solidify*.
5. A *Subdivision Surface* modifier, to smooth out the result.

The shader is procedural. It may seem a little elaborate, but it is founded on two re-usable node-groups, not all of whose features are used in this case.

1. A **'Shift-Grid'** node group:

[image]

This sets up a grid of rectangular cells, giving you:

- UV coordinates centered in each cell
- The position of the center of each cell in the original texture space
- The option to scale the size of each cell in Y, without scaling its internal UV
- The option to shift/stagger each column of cells,(used to make the rows of perforations diagonal, as in the reference)
- Distance from center of each cell
- Distance from edges of each cell, (used to make the knurling on the tape)

2. A **'Distance from Line-Segment'** group

[image]

- .. which, given 2 points, returns the distance of shading-points in the texture-space from the line-segment between them. It's used to make the capsule-shaped perforations in the tape.

They are used in this node-tree, to make the tape shader:

[image]

It can be assigned to the tape, using the UV coordinates provided by the *Screw* modifier:

[image]

[image]

I have no idea if this is how this tape should be deployed on a real bike :)